# I am trying to make foreign key constraint in my Schema using laravel but it is not reflecting in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

These are the attributes I want to reference  other tables

```
         $table->integer('carid')->references('id')->on('cars')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('userid')->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
```

On phpmyadmin
[This is how my php Admin looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQRp6.png)

I want to reference these attributes as foreign key where I am wrong?

Comment: Instead of declaring it as `integer` make it `foreign`

Comment: If you are having trouble, I suggest checking the docs, they are very good and you might find your answer much faster than writing up a question.  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use unsignedInteger() Datatype for this.

```
$table->unsignedInteger('carid')->nullable();
$table->foreign("carid")->references("id")->on("cars")->onDelete("CASCADE")->onUpdate("CASCADE");
```